# Docker: Share the same .so library different containers without compiling into each

Tags: c++, docker

Is there a way I could have multiple containers sharing a shared library inside the host machine without having to compile the library into each container.

I would like to allow people to test their code in containers using our testing library compiled into an `.so` but I don't want downloading and reverse-engineering it.

Is this possible at all?

**EDIT**

We do not allow people to manage images / containers (or pull these down to their local environments). We provide an interface that spins up containers under the hood. My question is whether or not it's possible to prevent people from writing code that downloads the `.so` in the images from which the container running the code was created.

My understanding is that every though Docker uses layers, it will still be possible for code inside a container to access everything that came with the image. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "without building the library into the image" instead of:

> without having to compile the library into each container

Then, no that's not possible. Distributing a docker image is just like a normal binary, there's nothing that will prevent anyone from reverse engineering it.

If the users of your image already have access to the `.so` somewhere on their host then you can simply have them mount it using a volume.

To clarify re:layers, this just means that if your `.so` happened to exist on disk at some point during the `docker build` process you can't just `rm` it if you don't want it accessible because the layer at which it existed will always be available.

Comment: Yeah, a user can simply do something like `docker cp CONTAINER:/lib/test.so ~/Documents/test.so`

Comment: To clarify, users can only run commands inside the container (in interactive mode for example). Can I prevent them from doing something like this: `insidethecontainer$ scp /lib/test.so user@somewhereelse:~/Downloads` either by having the library on a mounted volume or installed on the base image?

Comment: I see. In that case this becomes a linux security question, not particularly relevant to docker per se. I'm no expert with linux security but I imagine if you gave the file execute-only permission to other other users you would be fine: `RUN chmod 711 /lib/test.so`. Of course make sure you also set `USER something_not_root`.

Comment: I see. I'll try this. I thought there might be a docker-specific approach.

Comment: "If the users of your image already have access to the .so somewhere on their host then you can simply have them mount it using a volume."

Can you please explain this a bit further, I believe i need to do this for my current setup.